# Different alignment of separate \align environments

Tags: align

I made a document with two different align environments.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Geometric parameters}
\begin{align*}
&Area_{membrane}&           &\text{Active membrane area}\\
&n_{mod}&                   &\text{Number of modules in row}\\
&n_{env}&                   &\text{Number of wrappings per module}\\
&l_{mod}&                   &\text{Length of RO-module}\\
&t_f&                       &\text{Thickness of retentate/feedspacer}\\
&t_p&                   &\text{Thickness of permeatespacer}\\
&\varepsilon_{mem,permspacer}&  &\text{Porosity of permeatespacer}\\
&S_{V,mem,permspacer}&      &\text{Volume-specific Area of permeatespacer}\\
&\tau_{mem,permspacer}& &\text{Parameter for poregeometry of permeatespacer}\\
&\rho_{pp}&             &\text{Density of permeatespacer}\\
&c_{pp}&                    &\text{Heat capacity of pemeatespacer}
\end{align*}
%
\paragraph{Membrane and CP parameters}
\begin{align*}
&T_{mem,ref}&               &\text{Reference temperature for membrane}\\
&A_{mem,ref}&               &\text{Membrane permeability of water at\:}T_{ref}\\
&B_{mem,star,ref}&          &\text{Membrane permeability for salt at}\:T_{ref}\\
&\alpha_{mem}&          &\text{Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of water}\\
&\beta_{mem}&           &\text{Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of salt}\\
&k_{CP,ref}&                &\text{Reference coefficient of CP}\\
&\alpha_{CP}&               &\text{Exponent of influence of bulk velocity on CP}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following .pdf.
[image: Resulting .pdf]

How can I align the two align environments?

Comment: In my opinion, you should not use a math environment here: a list environment would be more sensible, from a semantic point of view.

Comment: or a use a table, then you have much more control of the size of the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Why no use `\intertext{...}` inside a single `align*`?. Something like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Geometric parameters}
\begin{align*}
&Area_{membrane}&           &\text{Active membrane area}\\
&n_{mod}&                   &\text{Number of modules in row}\\
&n_{env}&                   &\text{Number of wrappings per module}\\
&l_{mod}&                   &\text{Length of RO-module}\\
&t_f&                       &\text{Thickness of retentate/feedspacer}\\
&t_p&                   &\text{Thickness of permeatespacer}\\
&\varepsilon_{mem,permspacer}&  &\text{Porosity of permeatespacer}\\
&S_{V,mem,permspacer}&      &\text{Volume-specific Area of permeatespacer}\\
&\tau_{mem,permspacer}& &\text{Parameter for poregeometry of permeatespacer}\\
&\rho_{pp}&             &\text{Density of permeatespacer}\\
&c_{pp}&                    &\text{Heat capacity of pemeatespacer}
\intertext{\sectfont Membrane and CP parameters}
&T_{mem,ref}&               &\text{Reference temperature for membrane}\\
&A_{mem,ref}&               &\text{Membrane permeability of water at\:}T_{ref}\\
&B_{mem,star,ref}&          &\text{Membrane permeability for salt at}\:T_{ref}\\
&\alpha_{mem}&          &\text{Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of water}\\
&\beta_{mem}&           &\text{Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of salt}\\
&k_{CP,ref}&                &\text{Reference coefficient of CP}\\
&\alpha_{CP}&               &\text{Exponent of influence of bulk velocity on CP}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the  `enumitem` package. Such an environment can break across pages, while a tabular-type environment would requite using `longtable` or `ltablex`. The second `enumerate` environment is  aligned with the first one thanks to the `resume*` option which uses the parameters of the first list:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Geometric parameters}
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, labelwidth = 3cm, leftmargin = 3cm, itemsep=0pt]
\item[$\mathit{Area}_\mathrm{membrane}$] Active membrane area
\item[$n_\mathrm{mod}$] Number of modules in row
\item[$n_\mathrm{env}$] Number of wrappings per module
\item[$l_\mathrm{mod}$] Length of RO-module
\item[$t_f$] Thickness of retentate/feedspacer
\item[$t_p$] Thickness of permeatespacer
\item[$ε_\mathrm{mem, permspacer}$] Porosity of permeatespacer
\item[$S_{V , \mathrm{mem, permspacer}}$] Volume-specific Area of permeatespacer
\item[$τ_\mathrm{mem,permspacer}$] Parameter for poregeometry of permeatespacer
\item[$ρ_{pp}$] Density of permeatespacer
\item[$c_{pp}$] Heat capacity of pemeatespacer
\end{enumerate}
%
\paragraph{Membrane and CP parameters}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item[$T_\mathrm{mem,ref}$] Reference temperature for membrane
\item[$A_\mathrm{mem,ref}$] Membrane permeability of water at $ T_{ref} $
\item[$B_\mathrm{mem, star, ref}$] Membrane permeability for salt at $ T_{ref} $
\item[$α_\mathrm{mem}$] Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of water
\item[$β_\mathrm{mem}$] Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of salt
\item[$k_\mathrm{CP,ref}$] Reference coefficient of CP
\item[$α_\mathrm{CP}$] Exponent of influence of bulk velocity on CP
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using `align` in a situation like this really isn't a good idea.  for one thing,
it will limit the possibilities of where a page can be broken.

i think `tabbing` gives the simplest input, and one of the most flexible and reliable
as long as the information in the second column doesn't run to two lines.

in the following, the widest entry in the first column is identified and saved as
a macro, `\widestfirst`.  that makes it easy to change if the contents of one of
the lists changes.

i also made the assumption that the "words" in the first column really are terms that
should not be treated as math variables, and set them as `\text`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\widestfirst}{$S_{V,mem,permspacer}$\qquad}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\paragraph{Geometric parameters}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{1em} \= \widestfirst \= \kill
\> $\text{Area}_{\text{membrane}}$          \> Active membrane area\\
\> $n_{\text{mod}}$                  \> Number of modules in row\\
\> $n_{\text{env}}$                  \> Number of wrappings per module\\
\> $l_{\text{mod}}$                  \> Length of RO-module\\
\> $t_f$                      \> Thickness of retentate/feedspacer\\
\> $t_p$                  \> Thickness of permeatespacer\\
\> $\varepsilon_{\text{mem},\text{permspacer}}$ \> Porosity of permeatespacer\\
\> $S_{V,\text{mem},\text{permspacer}}$     \> Volume-specific Area of permeatespacer\\
\> $\tau_{\text{mem},\text{permspacer}}$\> Parameter for poregeometry of permeatespacer\\
\> $\rho_{pp}$            \> Density of permeatespacer\\
\> $c_{pp}$                   \> Heat capacity of permeatespacer
\end{tabbing}
%
\paragraph{Membrane and CP parameters}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{1em} \= \widestfirst \= \kill
\> $T_{\text{mem},\text{ref}}$              \> Reference temperature for membrane\\
\> $A_{\text{mem},\text{ref}}$              \> Membrane permeability of water at $T_{ref}$\\
\> $B_{\text{mem},\text{star},\text{ref}}$         \> Membrane permeability for salt at $T_{ref}$\\
\> $\alpha_{\text{mem}}$         \> Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of water\\
\> $\beta_{\text{mem}}$          \> Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of salt\\
\> $k_{\text{CP},\text{ref}}$               \> Reference coefficient of CP\\
\> $\alpha_{\text{CP}}$              \> Exponent of influence of bulk velocity on CP
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 0):

A table approach:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}%
}
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{\footnotesize #1}}}%
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=\string"8000 }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{Geometric parameters}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm} p{10cm}}
  \toprule
   \mc{Symbol}                     & \mc{Explanation} \\
  \midrule
   $\mathrm{area}_|membran|$       & Active membrane area \\
   $n_|mod|$                       & Number of modules in row \\
   $n_|env|$                       & Number of wrappings per module \\
   $l_|mod|$                       & Length of RO-module \\
   $t_{f}$                         & Thickness of retentate/feedspacer \\
   $t_{p}$                         & Thickness of permeatespacer \\
   $\varepsilon_|mem, permspacer|$ & Porosity of permeatespacer \\
   $S_|$V$, mem, permspacer|$      & Volume-specific area of permeatespacer \\
   $\tau_|mem, permspacer|$        & Parameter for poregeometry of permeatespacer \\
   $\rho_{pp}$                     & Density of permeatespacer \\
   $c_{pp}$                        & Heat capacity of pemeatespacer \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section*{Membrane and CP parameters}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm} p{10cm}}
  \toprule
   \mc{Symbol}          & \mc{Explanation} \\
  \midrule
   $T_|mem, ref|$       & Reference temperature for membrane \\
   $A_|mem, ref|$       & Membrane permeability of water at $T_|ref|$ \\
   $B_|mem, star, ref|$ & Membrane permeability for salt at $T_|ref|$ \\
   $\alpha_|mem|$       & Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of water \\
   $\beta_|mem|$        & Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of salt \\
   $k_|CP, ref|$        & Reference coefficient of CP \\
   $\alpha_|CP|$        & Exponent of influence of bulk velocity on CP \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

or

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}%
}
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{\footnotesize #1}}}%
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=\string"8000 }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{Geometric parameters}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm} l}
   $\mathrm{area}_|membran|$       & Active membrane area \\
   $n_|mod|$                       & Number of modules in row \\
   $n_|env|$                       & Number of wrappings per module \\
   $l_|mod|$                       & Length of RO-module \\
   $t_{f}$                         & Thickness of retentate/feedspacer \\
   $t_{p}$                         & Thickness of permeatespacer \\
   $\varepsilon_|mem, permspacer|$ & Porosity of permeatespacer \\
   $S_|$V$, mem, permspacer|$      & Volume-specific area of permeatespacer \\
   $\tau_|mem, permspacer|$        & Parameter for poregeometry of permeatespacer \\
   $\rho_{pp}$                     & Density of permeatespacer \\
   $c_{pp}$                        & Heat capacity of pemeatespacer \\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Membrane and CP parameters}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm} l}
   $T_|mem, ref|$       & Reference temperature for membrane \\
   $A_|mem, ref|$       & Membrane permeability of water at $T_|ref|$ \\
   $B_|mem, star, ref|$ & Membrane permeability for salt at $T_|ref|$ \\
   $\alpha_|mem|$       & Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of water \\
   $\beta_|mem|$        & Temperature coefficient of membrane permeability of salt \\
   $k_|CP, ref|$        & Reference coefficient of CP \\
   $\alpha_|CP|$        & Exponent of influence of bulk velocity on CP
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]